# Refactoring methods used to retrieve filter values from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, refactoring

I am using .Net Framework 4, mvc 3 and entity framework (latest stable)

On an index page I want to be able to filter each column. The filter values are retrieved for each column by LINQ using the distinct() method. I have not found a good way to reuse the method that retrieves these values for each column - they are basically equal, the only thing differentiating them is the column name used, so having one method instead of several would be great.

```
public List<string> GetLevels()
{
    return _db.Logs.Select(l => l.Level).Distinct().ToList();
}

public List<string> GetOrders()
{
    return _db.Logs.Select(l => l.Order).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

How can I inject the lambda expression with the column name I want to retrieve data from? Something like this:

```
public List<string> GetFilterValues(string columName)
{
    return _db.Logs.Select(l => l.columnName).Distinct.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing everything in one method, it'd be better if you make properties like: `public List<string> GetLevels
{
    get {return _db.Logs.Select(l => l.Level).Distinct().ToList(); }
}` It would be more readable. By the way, why do you want to have two different things in one method? I am sure that return value will be different.

Comment: @PLB, I agree, it's more readable. I still would like to know if it's possible to inject the column name into the expression though.

Comment: Yes it's and answer contains solution but if you use one it means that every time you call that method you have to pass expression which does not seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a function which takes an expression selecting the property you want:

```
public List<T> GetLogProperties<T>(Expression<Func<Log, T>> selector)
{
    return _db.Logs.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();
}

public List<string> GetLevels()
{
    return GetLogProperties(l => l.Level);
}
```

EDIT: If you want to create the projection from a string column, you will have to build the expression yourself:

```
public List<string> GetFilterValues(string columnName)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Log), "l");
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, columnName);
    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Log, string>>(propExpr, paramExpr);

    return _db.Logs.Select(lambdaExpr).Distinct().ToList();
}

List<string> levels = GetFilterValues("Level");
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the property with the given name is not a `string` property.

Comment: I like the simplicity of your first example better.